# store and get generic credentials with an intranet application

Tags: networkcredentials

I developed an Intranet application which needs to realize a "git push" from a local repository (on the disk of the web server) to a remote repository.
I launch the git process from the web server, it runs under the IIS pool identity which is a domain account member of the administrators group of the web server machine.
Git needs the user credentials to perform the push action. I integrated a custom version of git-credential-winstore. This program uses the **Windows Credential Manager** to store **generic credentials** for a web site. But when the call to the credential's write occurs, I get the error :

```
Failed to write credential: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated
```

I checked the policy "Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication", it is disabled.

What goes wrong here ?

Comment: Is there anybody here with experience with Windows vault ? I wonder if it's really possible to use it without a user open session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pool account needs to gain access to its user profile.
So we need to connect one time to a Windows Session to create user profile (I think it's necessary). Next in the Advanced Settings of the dedicated Application Pool, set "Load User Profile" = true.

Note about credentials : Windows credential target must be changed to manage different users in the same Windows vault. I change "git:https://remote-host" by "git_USERID:https://remote-host".

Answer (score 0):

I set this property to **enabled** and it works now, maybe it will work for you also:

[image]

Comment: Everyone says we need to keep it disabled for it to work. And you say it in reverse?